# How to remove data frame column with a single value

Tags: r, dataframe

Let say I have the following data frame in R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Item_Name = c("test1","test2","test3"), D_1=c(1,0,1),
                  D_2=c(1,1,1), D_3=c(11,3,1))
```

I would like to create a function that would delete columns with no variance
(e.g. in this case, it would remove column `D_2` because it has only 1 value)

I know that I could check it by hand, but in reality my data is very large and I would like to automate it. Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Filter` is a useful function here. I will filter only for those where there is more than 1 unique value.

i.e.

```
Filter(function(x)(length(unique(x))>1), df1)

##   Item_Name D_1 D_3
## 1     test1   1  11
## 2     test2   0   3
## 3     test3   1   1
```

Comment: would be more efficient if you checked `min(x)!=max(x)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864704/4137985)

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
df1[c(TRUE, lapply(df1[-1], var, na.rm = TRUE) != 0)]
#   Item_Name D_1 D_3
# 1     test1   1  11
# 2     test2   0   3
# 3     test3   1   1
```

where the `lapply` piece tells you what variables have some variance:

```
lapply(df1[-1], var, na.rm = TRUE) != 0
#   D_1   D_2   D_3 
#   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

In `dplyr`, we can use `n_distinct` to count unique values and `select_if` to select columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% select(where(~n_distinct(.) > 1))
#For dplyr < 1.0.0
#df1 %>% select_if(~n_distinct(.) > 1)

#  Item_Name D_1 D_3
#1     test1   1  11
#2     test2   0   3
#3     test3   1   1
```

We can use the same logic with `purrr`'s `keep` and `discard`

```
purrr::keep(df1, ~n_distinct(.) > 1)
purrr::discard(df1, ~n_distinct(.) == 1)
```

---

Apart from that `data.table` way of doing it could be

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
df1[, lapply(df1, uniqueN) > 1, with = FALSE]
```

Or probably this is smarter/better

```
df1[, .SD, .SDcols=lapply(df1, uniqueN) > 1]
```

---

In all the above approaches you could replace `n_distinct`/`uniqueN` with `var` or `sd` function after subsetting only numeric columns.

For example,

```
df1[-1] %>% select_if(~sd(.) != 0)
```